# Why is my value coming back undefined after a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

```
         var result = {},
            data={},
            access_token = result.access_token,
            baseURI = result.resource_server_base_uri;

        function getToken() {
            var query_string = {};
            var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
            var vars = query.split("&");
            for (var i=0; i < vars.length; i++) {
                var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                query_string[pair[0]] = pair[1];
            }
            if (typeof(query_string.access_token) != "undefined") {
                result.state = query_string.state;
                result.scope = decodeURIComponent(query_string.scope);
                result.access_token = decodeURIComponent(query_string.access_token);
                result.expires_in = query_string.expires_in;
                result.resource_server_base_uri = decodeURIComponent(query_string.resource_server_base_uri);
                result.token_type = query_string.token_type;
            }
        }

        function startSession(startSessionPayload){
                access_token = result.access_token;
                baseURI = result.resource_server_base_uri;

            return $http({
                'url': baseURI + 'services/v6.0/agent-sessions',
                'method': 'POST',
                'headers': {'Authorization': 'bearer ' + access_token, 'content-Type': 'application/json'},
                'data': startSessionPayload
            }).then(function(res){
                 data.sessionId = res.data.sessionId;
                console.log("sessionId", data.sessionId); <---shows session Id I need to use later
            });
        }

        console.log('SESSIONID', data.sessionId); <--- returns undefined
```

This code seems to successfully obtain the the sessionId I need from res, but when I try to apply it to the initiated data variable object (similarly to how I did with var result={}, and use it in other functions, it returns undefined. What am I screwing up?

Comment: in the code you've posted, you never execute any of the functions defined in the code ... and of course the usual sync/async consfusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the sequence of execution.

The code inside the function passed to **then** is the last to be executed.. You need to call all other functions which require **sessionId** after that. Something like this:

```
.then(function(res){
    data.sessionId = res.data.sessionId;
    console.log("sessionId", data.sessionId); <---shows session Id I need to use later
    anyOtherFunction(data.sessionId);
});

function anyOtherFunction(sessionId) {
    console.log('SESSIONID', sessionId); <--- not undefined
}
```

Comment: I see. How could I call 'function anyOtherFunction()' from a controller with the promise coming from an injected Factory?

Comment: the Factory should accept a callback as an argument or something. the promise should be always aware of a callback to be triggered.

Answer (score 2):

It is an asyncronous call and when you access that property on `data` object, it is abscent becuase it is not set yet. You have to do something like

```
function startSession(startSessionPayload){
            access_token = result.access_token;
            baseURI = result.resource_server_base_uri;

        return $http({
            'url': baseURI + 'services/v6.0/agent-sessions',
            'method': 'POST',
            'headers': {'Authorization': 'bearer ' + access_token, 'content-Type': 'application/json'},
            'data': startSessionPayload
        }).then(function(res){

             return res.data.sessionId;

        });
    }
```

and later call it like

```
startSession(payload).then(function(id){
   data.id = id;
  // do your logic here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you can't see the SessionId in the outer context is that this is a synchronous code which is executed immediately. The console.log in the function is asynchronous, meaning that it is executed when the result of the http-request comes in.

So (assuming that you actually run the function) the reason you won't be able to see it, is that the asynchronous `.then()` has not yet been executed.

Solution: return the promise instead:

```
function startSession(startSessionPayload){
                access_token = result.access_token;
                baseURI = result.resource_server_base_uri;

            return $http({
                'url': baseURI + 'services/v6.0/agent-sessions',
                'method': 'POST',
                'headers': {'Authorization': 'bearer ' + access_token, 'content-Type': 'application/json'},
                'data': startSessionPayload
            })
        }
```

Now in other parts (where you actually need the value) you can just use the `then()` to get the value.

Comment: I assumed It had something to do wit it. What's the best solution to resolve this?

Comment: The recommend approach is to keep everything async until you need it. So return the $http-promise in the function

Answer (score 0):

As other answers wrote, this is an async value.
The best solution, in my opinion, is to use resolve before routing to the page  that need a session-id.
i.e:

```
angular.module('app').config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('need-session', {
    templateUrl: 'your-page-template',
    controller:  'your-page-controller',
    resolve: {
      sessionId: function($http) {
        return $http({
            'url': baseURI + 'services/v6.0/agent-sessions',
            'method': 'POST',
            'headers': {'Authorization': 'bearer ' + access_token, 'content-Type': 'application/json'},
            'data': startSessionPayload
        }).then(function(res){
             return res.data.sessionId;
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

And then retrieve it via the controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('your-page-controller', function($scope, sessionId) {
  //Use the sessionId as needed
});
```

Hope that help

Comment: I was trying to avoid putting it in $scope, since the value is never really in need of being updated. Do you know if one way is a better practice than the other?

Comment: Well, it's up to you where to store it. You can instead use the variable in the controller as it is.